# I'd like to add a second "Save" button that saves the node as usual, but I can use a module to alter the node

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

EDIT: Answered below.

Bit of a weird one. I'd like a second Save button that saves a node but that I could target with some php.

`Save` `Save Progress` `Cancel`

My use-case isn't as simple as using [Autosave](https://www.drupal.org/project/autosave) and I don't want to start installing WorkBench or any other module for a small feature.

I could have a taxonomy field above the save where users can choose, but really, I'd prefer a second Save button for UI reasons. I could also use jQuery and have psuedo-buttons that click the appropriate term and then the save button, but I'd rather do it programmatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this with a validate handler instead of a submit handler. I'm not sure of the implications of that but it works.

```
<?php

function custom_assignment_save_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "assignment_node_form") {
        $form['secondsubmit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save Progress'),
        '#weight' => 100,
        '#validate' => array('node_form_validate', 'custom_assignment_save_form_validate'),
        '#submit' => array('node_form_submit'),
      );
    }
}
function custom_assignment_save_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    form_set_value($form['field_boolean'], array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('value' => 1))), $form_state);
}
```

This simply changes a hidden boolean value when the `Save Progress` submit button is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom submit handler and then your own callback to do whatever you want.

The basic approach is:

1. Using `hook_form_alter()` to target the relevant form, add another submit button that calls your callback function.
2. Write the callback function to do whatever you want to do.

[Here's an example](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/code/attach-custom-submit-handler-drupal-form):

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = "my_module_form_submit_handler";
}

function my_module_form_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message("The form is being submitted, do some extra stuff now...");
}
```

Comment: Ah, that sounds like the exact start I need. I'll work on it tomorrow and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, but this doesn't address the `I'd like add a second save button` part.

Comment: @NoSssweat In step 1, I suggest using `hook_form_alter()` to "add another submit button."  I didn't provide a code example, but I did address the question.

Comment: I've posted an answer after working at it for a while this morning. Your pointer led me in the right direction.